# How to animate particles flow with distortion on the surface of the object?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, animation-nodes, force-fields

My first post here.

I have problem to solve - generate particle animation like in this photo (using Animation Nodes):

[image: Reference image]

but on the surface of this 3d car shell:

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve such result?
Or give me a little hint how to approach the problem?
I need particles to flow but stay on the surface of the car.

Best regards
MM

Comment: Suggestion.  Consider projecting points/paths to surface of car as location of your particles. [Shrinkwrap Modifier] You may want to state how familiar you are with Python.  Geometry nodes perhaps.

Comment: Suggestion.  Consider Particles of Fluid type with Forces.

Comment: Suggestion change your car to have a particle system on it with a fleet foot.  Fluid type.  Temporary or permanent. This should be less than 38 minutes.  This will allow you to think about the problem more clearly.

Comment: Is the (pseudo) liquid flowing as though a single force exists, such as gravity?  Or does it flow as though in a turbulence field? You can answer this in your original question. The car, and mesh duplicates, can be an obstacle and a force of positive and negative strength. There are multiple forces available. Be prepared for many trials.